# General solution to $\operatorname{div}\vec u + (\vec v, \vec u) = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

Doing some physics, I've stumbled upon a following equation:
$$\operatorname{div}\vec{u} + (\vec{v}, \vec{u}) = 0$$

Where $\vec{v}(x, y, z)$ is known. If it gives any help, $\vec{v}(x, y, z) = \operatorname{grad}g(x, y, z)$ and $\vec{u}(x, y, z) = \operatorname{grad}f(x, y, z)$,  where $g(x, y, z) \geq 0$ is known real-valued scalar function and $f(x, y, z)$ is an unknown scalar real-valued function.

I would like to obtain a more or less explicit form of $u$, i.e. express $u$ in terms of $v$.

In the case of 1D, the equation simplifies to
$$u' + vu = 0$$
Which is obviously solved by separation of variables and yields a single-parameter set of solutions
$$u(x) = C e^{-\int v(x)\,dx}$$

In 3D, solving is far from being straightgorward. It seems that modifying the Bogovskii operator may be not senseless (say Geißert, 2006), but I don't have much experience in the area and I'm afraid of taking wrong direction from the beginning.

I would appreciate for any hints on methods of solving this, as well any references to the books or articles on close topics.

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{div}u$ can be coded as \operatorname{div}u. This is not the same as \text{div} u or \mathrm{div} u, in that it has context-dependent spacing, so that in $\operatorname{div}(u),$ coded as \operatorname{div}(u), the amount of space to the right of $\operatorname{div}$ is smaller than it is in $\operatorname{div}u,$ and the same context-dependence holds to the left of $\operatorname{div}. \qquad$

Comment: Well one set of solutions is obviously $u = (u_1,u_2,u_3)$ with $u_1(x,y,z) = C(y,z)e^{-g(x,y,z)}$, $u_2(x,y,z) = C(x,z)e^{-g(x,y,z)}$, and $u_3(x,y,z) = C(x,y)e^{-g(x,y,z)}$.

Comment: I think you might want to say $\vec u = \nabla f$ rather than $\vec u = \nabla \cdot f$ since $f$ is a scalar and $\vec u$ a vector; for a scalar $\nabla \cdot f$ doesn't mean anything, hence my suggestion.  Similarly for $\vec v$. Cheers!

Comment: This can't be generally solved. Would you add some more constraints?

Comment: The vector $\vec u(x,y,z)$ is comprised of three unknown scalar functions.  The PDE $\nabla \cdot \vec u=\vec v\cdot\vec u$ is only one equation for the three scalar unknowns.  There is no unique solution even after prescribing boundary conditions.

Comment: Above, I intended to write $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$. It's not supposed to be the same function $C$.

Comment: To @MarkViola: but the fact that $\vec{u} = \nabla{f}$ and $\vec{v} = \nabla{g}$ makes the components dependent. Does it mean that I should have looked at the equation $\Delta{f} + \nabla{g}\cdot\nabla{f} = 0$ instead, as on being more specific?

Comment: I missed that.   So, you have the equation $\nabla^2 f+\vec v\cdot \nabla f=0$ but you have not prescribed boundary conditions.  Moreover, while $v$ is "known," the value of $f$ will depend on $v$'s being specified.  In general, I suspect that one would resort to a numerical solution using finite differences or by converting to an integral equation and using the method of moments or similar approach.